# SQL pivoting and calculating difference between dates stored as strings - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, mariadb

I have two tables. First one is called `posts`, and a second one `postmeta`. (If someone notices, I'm working with a Wordpress db which is not important to know for this task).

`posts` table looks like this (for this purposes shortened).

```
ID  |  post_title | post_status | post_type
------------------------------------------
1   |  One        | publish     | hours
2   |  Two        | publish     | hours
```

`postmeta` table looks like this. Date format is d.m.Y. G:i:s.

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
------------------------------------------
1       | 1       | from     | 1.1.2017. 10:00:00
2       | 1       | to       | 1.1.2017. 16:00:00
3       | 2       | from     | 2.1.2017. 12:00:00
4       | 2       | to       | 2.1.2017. 15:00:00
```

In those tables `ID` = `post_id`.
The wanted result is a table below where `date_diff` is a difference between `from` and `to` in hours which has to be calculated by SQL (date_diff = to - from). Note that `meta_key` is defined as `VARCHAR` and `meta_value` as `LONGTEXT` which makes calculation harder.

```
ID | title | from               | to                 | date_diff
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1     | 1.1.2017. 10:00:00 | 1.1.2017. 16:00:00 | 6
2  | 1     | 2.1.2017. 12:00:00 | 2.1.2017. 15:00:00 | 3
```

This is the code I have for now. Making rows become columns is a bit problematic for me, and a calculation even more.

```
SELECT posts.ID, posts.post_title, postmeta.meta_key, postmeta.meta_value 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN postmeta 
ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id
WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
AND post_type = 'hours' 
AND (postmeta.meta_key = 'from' OR postmeta.meta_key = 'to');
```

Thanks alot. :)

Comment: I think you've made a mistake in your data set. What's post_id = 3 !?!

Comment: oh sorry, typo, it's 2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a self join on postmeta for get the two separated  columns 
use str_to_date for convert string in date 
use proper backtics for reserved  words (eg:from)
and TIMESTAMPDIFF for get the HOURS of diff

```
  SELECT 
          posts.ID
        , posts.post_title
        , str_to_date(table_from.meta_value, '%d.%m.%Y. %H:%i:%s')  as `from` 
        , str_to_date(table_to.meta_value, '%d.%m.%Y. %H:%i:%s' ) as `to` 
        , TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, str_to_date(table_from.meta_value, '%d.%m.%Y. %H:%i:%s') , 
                                    str_to_date(table_to.meta_value, '%d.%m.%Y. %H:%i:%s' )) as diff
  FROM posts
  INNER JOIN postmeta table_from ON posts.ID = table_from.post_id and table_from.meta_key ='from'
  inner join postmeta table_to ON posts.ID = table_to.post_id and table_to.meta_key ='to'
  WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
  AND post_type = 'hours'
```

for decimal you can use

timestampdiff(MINUTE, startdate, enddate)/60 as diff

Comment: Thanks for reply, tried the code but from, to and diff have only NULL values.

Comment: While testing the code I noticed that str_to_date returns NULL, so probably that is the cause, but still, not working, however, it is very close.

Comment: could be the date format  ... missing a dot after the Year .. answer  updated  with the dot.

Comment: if you use 24 hours  the format must be H  and not h .. answer  updated

Comment: It works, is it possible for TIMESTAMPDIFF to show hours in decimals, e.g. 1.5 hour because for now it shows only whole hours? :D

Answer (score 1):

E.g. (slower than Scaisedge's method, but easier to read...)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts;

CREATE TABLE posts
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,post_title VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,post_status VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,post_type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO posts VALUES
(1,'One','publish','hours'),
(2,'Two','publish','hours');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS postmeta;

CREATE TABLE postmeta
(meta_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,post_id INT NOT NULL
,meta_key VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,meta_value VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO postmeta VALUES
(1,1,'from','1.1.2017. 10:00:00'),
(2,1,'to'  ,'1.1.2017. 16:00:00'),
(3,2,'from','2.1.2017. 12:00:00'),
(4,2,'to'  ,'2.1.2017. 15:00:00');

-- Date format is d.m.Y. H:i:s.

SELECT post_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'from' THEN STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d.%m.%Y. %H:%i:%s') END) `from`
     , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'to' THEN STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d.%m.%Y. %H:%i:%s') END) `to`
     , TIMEDIFF(
           MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'to' THEN STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d.%m.%Y. %H:%i:%s') END)
         , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'from' THEN STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d.%m.%Y. %H:%i:%s') END)
               ) date_diff
  FROM postmeta 
 GROUP 
    BY post_id;

+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| post_id | from                | to                  | date_diff |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2017-01-01 10:00:00 | 2017-01-01 16:00:00 | 06:00:00  |
|       2 | 2017-01-02 12:00:00 | 2017-01-02 15:00:00 | 03:00:00  |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

I've left the final part as an (easy) exercise for the reader.

Comment: Strawberry, thank you for your answer, it is amazing, unfortunately I can take only one answer as a correct. You put an effort to answer so the smallest thing I can do is to upvote it ;) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I wish it will be helpful.

```
SELECT 
   p.id, 
   p.post_title, 
   postmeta_temp.from, 
   postmeta_temp.to, 
   postmeta_temp.date_diff 
FROM   posts p 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT postmeta_from.post_id 
                      AS post_id, 
                      postmeta_from.meta_key 
                                     AS from, 
                      postmeta_to.meta_key 
                                     AS to, 
                      Date_diff(postmeta_to.meta_value, 
                      postmeta_from.meta_value) 
                                     AS date_diff 
               FROM   postmeta postmeta_from 

                      INNER JOIN postmeta postmeta_to 

                              ON postmeta_from.post_id = postmeta_to.post_id 

                                 AND postmeta_from.meta_key = 'from' 

                                 AND postmeta_to.meta_key = 'to') AS 

              postmeta_temp 

           ON p.id = postmeta_temp.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

For every ID I would check next time with same ID and next date.

```
select pm.post_id as ID, pm.post_id as title, pm.metavalue as from,  
(select x.metavalue from postmeta x where x.enter code herepost_id = pm.post_id and not x.meta_key = 'from') 
as to , 
(select cast(x.metavalue as timestamp) - cast(pm.metavalue as timestamp) from postmeta x 
      where x.post_id = pm.post_id and not x.meta_key = 'from') as date_diff from 
postmeta pm where pm.meta_key = 'from';


 id | title |        from        |         to         | date_diff 
----+-------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------
  1 |     1 | 1.1.2017. 10:00:00 | 1.1.2017. 16:00:00 | 06:00:00
  2 |     2 | 2.1.2017. 12:00:00 | 2.1.2017. 15:00:00 | 03:00:00
```